# fillPolygon in Canvas / Surface

Tags: playn

is there some way to perform the java AWT Graphics.fillPolygon  method 
in a Surface or a Canvas of playn framework ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use [Path](http://docs.playn.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/playn/core/Path.html) and [Canvas.fillPath](http://docs.playn.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/playn/core/Canvas.html#fillPath%28playn.core.Path%29).

Reading the Javadocs for the main PlayN classes will save you from the slow process of asking and waiting for an answer on Stack Overflow for such trivial questions in the future.